# Is there a way to customize Firebug's keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: debugging, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firebug

Is there a way to customize Firebug's keyboard shortcuts?  I love being able to step through JavaScript code using Firebug's *Script* panel, but it looks like I'm limited to either using the default keyboard shortcuts for stepping over/into/out of code or using the mouse to click the appropriate button.

Am I missing something?

Is there some secret **about:config** hack in Firefox/Firebug that would help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change them manually. Go to this directory:

In recent versions the extension comes in a single file with the extension XPI. Just rename it to ZIP, create a directory and extract its contents into it.

Linux:

```
.mozilla/firefox/*****.default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com/
```

Windows:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt.com\
```

Then modify this file (these are my remapping settings):

**content/firebug/debugger/script/scriptPanel.js** (Firebug 2.0)

```
    this.keyListeners =
    [
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F5", Events.isShift, Obj.bind(this.rerun, this, context), true),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F5", null, Obj.bind(this.resume, this, context), true),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F6", null, Obj.bind(this.stepOver, this, context), true),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F7", null, Obj.bind(this.stepInto, this, context)),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F8", null, Obj.bind(this.stepOut, this, context))
    ];
```

**content/firebug/js/scriptPanel.js** (before Firebug 2.0)

```
    this.keyListeners =
    [
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F5", null, Obj.bind(this.resume, this, context), true),
        chrome.keyListen("/", Events.isControl, Obj.bind(this.resume, this, context)),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F6", null, Obj.bind(this.stepOver, this, context), true),
        chrome.keyListen("'", Events.isControl, Obj.bind(this.stepOver, this, context)),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F7", null, Obj.bind(this.stepInto, this, context)),
        chrome.keyListen(";", Events.isControl, Obj.bind(this.stepInto, this, context)),
        chrome.keyCodeListen("F8", null, Obj.bind(this.stepOut, this, context)),
        chrome.keyListen(",", Events.isControlShift, Obj.bind(this.stepOut, this, context))
    ];
```

In versions before 2.0 you should also change the localization file, so the tooltips should the correct keys:

**locale/en-US/firebug.properties**

```
firebug.Continue=Continue (F5)
firebug.StepOver=Step Over (F6)
firebug.StepInto=Step Into (F7)
firebug.StepOut=Step Out (F8)
```

And that is all. Unfortunately, you have to do it every time you update Firebug. Though there is already a [request to allow their customization directly within Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/2665).

Comment: You're welcome! I think it's important to keep old answers up-to-date.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in their [discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/tgDCmsg89yE), you can try [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)... otherwise, it is a [known bug/limitation](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/2665).

Answer (score 2):

As @VonC mentioned, there is an open ticket on this.  In my experience, keyconfig doesn't work for this purpose.  I did [write a patch](http://blog.kaeding.name/articles/2008/12/11/customize-firebug-shortcut-keys) that allows for the debugger execution control keys to be customized in about:config.  I have also posted an XPI with this fix if you don't want to wait for it to be accepted upstream, and/or you don't want to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to configure the shortcuts manually in file

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt.com\content\firebug\browserOverlay.xul
```

For example, I removed the shortcut on F12 by commenting the corresponding section because it conflicts with the *Undo Closed Tab* shortcut of Tab Mix Plus.

Disadvantage: An update of Firebug will overwrite the modified configuration.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to [change the shortcuts within Firebug's source code](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/debugger/script/scriptPanel.js#L1552-L1556), there is also a way to add different keys for those actions without touching the source.

To do so you have to install an extension, which allows you to define custom shortcuts like [Dorando keyconfig](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/).

**Steps to do for that extension:**

1. Go to the Add-ons Manager.
2. Click the *Options* button besides the extension to open the customization dialog.
3. Click the *Add a new key* button to open the key editor.
4. Give the shortcut a proper name
5. Paste the [code related to the action](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/firefox/firebugMenuOverlay.xul)* into the code field.
6. Click *OK*
7. Click into the shortcut field
8. Add a custom shortcut by pressing the keys on the keyboard
9. Click the *Apply* button

**Screenshots for clarification:**

[image: Dorando keyconfig key customization dialog]
[image: Dorando keyconfig key editor]

* That is the value of the `oncommand` attribute. So, if you want to add a shortcut for resuming the JavaScript execution, you need to copy `Firebug.Debugger.resume(Firebug.currentContext)` from the `cmd_firebug_resumeExecution` command.